# Does iostream use overloads or templates?

Tags: c++, templates, system-calls, overloading

I'm trying to make the write() system call a little easier for my class. It won't take the 
destination and size parameters, but instead, only the object. Templates seem the best solution, but I've got some troubles when dealing with arrays, e.g.
The C++ I/O functions had to manage this situation as well, then I'd like to know how they were implemented. We don't care that for the compiler templates and overloads are basically the same thing.
I will also overload the << operator, to <s>sweeten the syntax</s> make it even easier to use.

**How the function should work like**
The member function should let you send data to a certain fd. It should look like so:

```
string s = "Hello World!";
double array[10];
int s = 50;
send(s); 
send(array);
send(s);
```

For the strings, I've overloaded the function just for `const char*` and it works (`strlen` is much better than `sizeof` in that case).

Comment: Can you give us a code example?

Comment: About how the function should work or how I've coded it?

Comment: I was thinking the first one but both should do. :)

Comment: @black Edit your question with such stuff, please!!

Comment: IOStreams uses overloads. I don't exactly understand what you're description is asking though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOStreams don't have any overloads dealing with arrays. The streams can deal with C-style strings, i.e., a pointers to a null-character terminated sequences of `char` (or `wchar_t` when using wide character streams). That said you *can* deduce the size of a statically sized array in C++:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
void print_size(T (&array)[Size]) {
    std::cout << "size=" << Size << '\n';
}
```

Note, however, that I *don't* consider it a good idea to use template like the above to determine the amount of memory which needs to be written: just writing the bytes constituting an object clearly only works for PODs and even then it is a bad idea because there are fairly few guarantees about the layout of the objects. You are always better of properly serializing the objects where the serialized representation may be a binary representation which is pretty close to the way objects are [currently] represented in memory. However, specifying exactly how the data is serialized has benefits, e.g., when the data needs to be transferred between platform. Sure, that will never happen - until it does: if the software is any good, transferring data between system will be necessary.

The other realization is that plain arrays are actually quite uncommon. Instead, different containers are being used. To serialize them immediately what is really needed is a range abstraction with arrays just becoming a special kind of array.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, because I think that the answer from  Dietmar Kühl is good enough to answer your "main" question, a more appropriate interface for a function that uses `array` as an argument where `array` is declared as `double array[10];` is `foo (double * const array)` ( I'm not considering the pointer vs pointer to pointer problem with this interface, it's just a toy example to show the difference ).

My point is that in terms of declaration as a type, an array is much more similar to `T* const` than `const T *`, and in my experience many people confuse the two declaration thinking that an array is more like the last one than the first one.

You can safely assume that

```
double arr[10];
```

is a declaration almost identical to

```
double * const arr;
```

the only real difference is that with the last one you don't get an extra of other 9 positions for other 9 references to `double`s where the first one allocates a contiguos chunk of memory of a given size for the given `T`.